# NTLMv2 authorization using Axis 1.4

Tags: jakarta-ee, apache-axis, axis, ntlm, ntlmv2

I have a working application (JEE6) using Axis1.4 library to make SOAP requests to service behind NTLM authorization.

After the service provider did the OS upgrade on their side, my requests started receiving 401 (unauthorized) status.

I believe the cause is newer authorization (suppose NTLMv2). I used Axis 1.4 to generate all my stub and proxy classes in Java, is there a way I could easily modify them to be able to work with newer NTLMv2 authorization?

Answer (score 1):

The Jespa library is good solution for this type of thing. Specifically, if you can make your code use the jespa.http.HttpUrlConnection for making HTTP requests, it will do NTLMv2 *properly*.